# mysql select table from anther table from $_GET

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to select id from sub where mainid = $cccc  as iiid  and after that select from ads where cat = iiid

and select order from ads order by id desc limit 10

```
$cccc=intval($_GET['cat']);
$DB = new DB;
$seleddcddddtMainwork ="select id from sub where mainid='$cccc' as iiid from ads where cat='$idididid' order by id desc limit 10  ";
```

I tried many codes with that but it's not work with me.

I tried:

```
select sub.mainid='$cccc' as idididid  from ads where cat='$idididid' order by id desc limit 10
```

but I need to get id from sub where  mainid=cccc  and ahter that select from ads where cat = that id

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ads` (
  `id` int(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `photo` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `message` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `contery` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mobile` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `showmobile` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `showj` int(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `youtuube` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `photo` (`photo`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
  KEY `message` (`message`),
  KEY `price` (`price`),
  KEY `contery` (`contery`),
  KEY `mobile` (`mobile`),
  KEY `showmobile` (`showmobile`),
  KEY `show` (`showj`),
  KEY `youtuube` (`youtuube`),
  KEY `userid` (`userid`),
  KEY `cat` (`cat`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sub` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `mainid` int(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `mainid` (`mainid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=126 ;
```

My last try was:

```
select id from sub.mainid='$cccc' as idididid  from ads where cat='idididid' order by id desc limit 10
```

did not work either.

All I have one value `$cccc=intval($_GET['cat']);` that I need to select id from sub where mainid=$cccc as iit and select from ads where cat=iit

**Another thing**

```
SELECT sub.id, sub.mainid
FROM sub                                                                                     
WHERE sub.mainid =  '2'
```

and

result of this  sub.id  result  from ads where cat = sub.id

Comment: Please post the `CREATE TABLE` statements for these two tables so we can see the structure. Probably you need some kind of join query, but right now it's mostly just incomprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you do a join? If you want to select the id from table #1 in table #2, then you should join the two tables by the id value:

```
$cccc=intval($_GET['cat']);
$DB = new DB;
$seleddcddddtMainwork ="select S.id from sub S JOIN ads A ON S.mainid=A.id AND C.cat='$idididid' AND S.mainid='$cccc' order by S.id desc limit 10";
```

Make sure you select all the columns you need. In the query above, only the column id from the sub table is being selected:

select **S.id** from ....

To select the columns id, name and mainid from sub and the field message and price from ads:

```
$cccc=intval($_GET['cat']);
$DB = new DB;
$seleddcddddtMainwork ="select S.id, S.name, S.mainid, A.message, A.price from sub S JOIN ads A ON S.id=A.mainidAND C.cat='$idididid' AND S.mainid='$cccc' order by S.id desc limit 10";
```

Edit:

I changed the JOIN ON 'S.id=A.id' to 'S.id=A.mainid' I believe those are the ids you want to join.

In response to your comment:

> all i have one value $cccc=intval($_GET['cat']); that i need to select
>   id from sub where mainid=$cccc as iit and select from ads where
>   cat=iit

You can do the following:

```
$cccc=intval($_GET['cat']);
$DB = new DB;
$seleddcddddtMainwork ="select S.id, S.name, S.mainid as iit, A.message, A.price from sub S JOIN ads A ON S.mainid=A.cat AND S.mainid='$cccc' order by A.id desc limit 10";
```

Comment: all i have one value $cccc=intval($_GET['cat']);
that i need to select id from sub where mainid=$cccc   as iit  and select from ads where cat=iit

Comment: You can do a join on sub.mainid=ads.cat. See my changed above.

Comment: not work with me    i need to select id from sub where mainid=$cccc   as iit and select from ads where cat=iit

Comment: The very last query I gave in response to your previous comment should do what you requested. If you are receiving a mySQL error, then post the error and I may be able to help. if you want to select id from sub where sub.mainid="$cccc" and the same values from ads where cat= sub.mainid, you need to select the columns you need from subs and ads and join the two tables on sub.mainid=ads.cat AND sub.mainid="$ccc" the last query I posted should do that: select S.id, S.name, S.mainid, A.message, A.price from sub S JOIN ads A ON S.mainid=A.cat AND S.mainid='$cccc' order by A.id desc limit 10

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0005 sec )
SELECT S.id, S.name, S.mainid AS iit, A.message, A.price
FROM sub S
JOIN ads A ON S.mainid = A.cat
AND S.mainid =  '$cccc'
ORDER BY A.id DESC 
LIMIT 10

Comment: select S.id,  S.mainid  from sub S JOIN ads A ON S.mainid=A.cat where S.mainid='2' can you help me with that code?

Comment: SELECT sub.id, sub.mainid
FROM sub                                                                                     
WHERE sub.mainid =  '2'                                                                and result of this i need to get id from ads where cat = sub.id

Comment: for: select S.id, S.mainid from sub S JOIN ads A ON S.mainid=A.cat where S.mainid='2' There is an error. It should be "AND" not "where". So it should read: select S.id, S.mainid from sub S JOIN ads A ON S.mainid=A.cat AND S.mainid='2'